# IAR simulation mode printf is crashed

Tags: stm32, simulator, iar

I am facing a issue in STM32L425 with IAR simulation mode. I recently try to implement unit test in an existing Embedded project. while using i used printf to print the information for that i enabled semi hosting option and everything when ever i call printf my code is getting crashed.

Comment: Check if your project overrides printf or the underlying write function. If any of them is defined in the project it will take precedence over the version from the compiler library.

Comment: And don't forget to check for putchar(). Depending on your project settings IAR uses putchar() or write() as low level output.